# contest: watermarks and logos?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, contest

We have a restriction against artificial borders in the contest photos; do we also want to restrict watermarks and text? I thought we *did*, but on rereading, it's unclear. The original rules had:

**Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**

added [in July 12](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2351/2) with the "borders or of" just like that, and I apparently copied that right into the new rules and no one caught it. I *thinK* that was intended to say "borders or decorations" or "borders or watermarks", but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the limited space in the header, and because we've done very well with hundreds of great entries without 'em, I'd like to clarify the wording to disallow all *added* decoration, text, and logos.

Comment: If the photo is of a table on which there is a CocaCola bottle, should I retouch away with the company logo?

Comment: That wasn't my intent, and I've clarified the wording, but I think in general if a corporate logo is the primary subject of a photo, we would want to avoid it. If it's incidental to the image, it doesn't matter.

Comment: We also don't want the header image to turn into an ad space, I don't think. While you can get from the header (or contest entries) to a profile and discover that the shooter is a pro you might want to hire, I rather think that the good folks at StackExchange/StackOverflow would like to see some revenue from any ads that appear on the site (and that's kind of the point of watermarks that don't obliterate the photo).

Comment: I'm marking this accepted as it has pretty good support and no dissenting voices.